# Windows XP: Nvidia GeForce 6100 Brightness

Tags: windows-xp, nvidia-geforce, brightness

I have an Nvidia GeForce 6100 and using XP. I also have a SmartBoard.

my brightness settings are completely changed and are not good.

I tried changing the settings at the Nvidia GeForce 6100 nForce 430 color correction settings.

I cannot get any ideal, it's just way to bright, what do i have to do? I already tried my monitor brightness settings and the smartboard brightness settings. it does not matter. I think there are problems with the pixels.
How can i fix this? Is there something wrong with my video card?

Comment: What do you mean? You're turning down the Brightness and Contrast of your monitor and it's still way to bright?

Answer (score 1):

Have you reset your monitor, the SmartBoard, and your NVIDIA drivers to (factory) defaults, and *then* tried adjusting from there?

> - If you have the NVIDIA control panel you can click on the "*Restore Default*" link in the upper right of the window under **`Display>Adjust Desktop Color Settings`**.
> - Monitors generally have a menu option that you can access from the settings buttons on their front/side.
> - I'll give you the benefit of the doubt on finding the settings for the SmartBoard. [That, and I don't have the software/hardware anywhere near me to direct you].

Also, you should take the opportunity to make sure your drivers for the card/board(s) are up to date.